# punctuation to indicate non-grammatical pause or omission

Tags: punctuation, conversation

Is it inappropriate to use an ellipsis to create a conversational pause in a typed sentence, in a situation where it's not appropriate to use a comma or a dash or anything else? There's no grammatical pause; there's just a conversational pause that would be present if the typed sentence were spoken aloud.

Example (from a comment that I posted on a Buzzfeed video):
"So many props for using 'risen' correctly...and then rescinded for placing a redundant 'up' behind it."

Can I correctly use the ellipsis that way?

Comment: An ellipse is a geometrical figure.  Ellipses (plural of *ellipsis*) are the dots. For comments attached to an online video (especially a Buzzfeed video), you have my permission to do whatever you want.

Comment: To avoid the appearance of having dropped words, you can also use [em dashes](http://grammarist.com/grammar/emdash/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  As explained [here](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/ellipses.html), ellipses in dialogue text are often used in that way.  They usually indicate a pause in speech or a trailing-off effect, so the way you used them in your example is perfectly appropriate.